# Split table in two side of same page in jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I want to break the table in two side of the same page like if table has 200 rows & the page holds 100 rows then next 100 row will print next side of same page instead in new page.How to do this, could not figure out doing search.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The [Jasper Reports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf) has some information about this.

As a starting point, take a look at the "Filling Order" topic on page 21, and the "Column Count" topic on page 42.

Answer (score 0):

Try Report Properties --> Page columns --> Column Count:2

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: The Column Count property divedes in columns for the Detail section in the report. It can be filled vertically (from top to bottom, then goes to the next column) or vertically (from left to right and then bottom).